# Trying to create a link in a custom module

Tags: 8

I have the following code
  `  class PopularContentParselyBlock extends BlockBase {

```
 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */

 public function build() {
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.APIURL.com');
 $decoded = json_decode($res->getBody(),TRUE);
 foreach($decoded['data'] as $article) {
    $url = Url::fromUri( $article['url']);
    $endpoint = Link::fromTextAndUrl($article['title'], $url);

    }
  return $endpoint->toRenderable();
  }
}
```

`

When it prints out though all I get us Object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you printing it? Ideally it should be in a template but because Twig understands render arrays I'm assuming not?

Comment: This is the end of the class.  Sorry I forgot to add it to start.

}
    return [
      '#markup' => $endpoint,
    ];
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#markup` is used for content that has already been rendered. As the caller seems to be expecting a render array, you can just return it directly:

```
return $endpoint->toRenderable();
```

Comment: That yields this error:

Call to a member function toRenderable() on string

Comment: Hmm.  I have this in a foreach loop and if I don't concatenate items onto $endpoint it works.

Comment: That error doesn't really make sense in this narrow context, maybe you can edit the question and add the full code for this function? And what it is e.g. Controller?

Comment: It's a block so in a Plugin.  Code is updated.  That works.  But there are 5 urls that need created

Comment: This was the closest to what I needed to do to get this to work.  Turns out that making $endpoint an array and then looping through that array in the twig template produced what we needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the links in some kind of a render array, for example:

```
$build['links'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'links',
  '#links' => $links,
);
return $build;
```

Comment: After a meeting this afternoon I realized I probably need to just have this array of links sent off to a twig template where a foreach in there would output what I need.  Going to try your suggestion though.

Comment: Look at the documentation, you need a sub array of href and title, no need for the link function, the template is doing this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!links.html.twig/8